# StartApp mediation via AdMob

Tags: android, admob, ads

I'm currently using AdMob in my application and I would like to integrate StartApp

But I want to manage it via AdMob mediation, what is the way to do it (I can't find any documenation so far and their support doesn't answer about it) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to write a CustomEvent in which you make youy call to StartApp. You then add your CustomEvent into your mediation config in your Admob dashboard.

Have a look at

- [Admob Mediation](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/mediation) (Item 7)
- [Custom Events](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/training/mediation/custom-events/)

Comment: i'm watching the docs, my doubt is if i must use different jars to use mediation instead the Google Play Services or the StartApp "normal" jar provided. I say because i remember that with another networks like AppFlood or MobFox in the past there were specific admob mediation jar...

Comment: You need to use Google Play Services jar and then you need to add the jars for the extra networks, and for some networks they also have separate admob-networks adapter jars. But most just include those classes in their networks jars.

Comment: Ok!! I've figured out the Admob Adapter in the StartApp webpage https://developers.startapp.com/Dashboard/GetSDK.aspx